# Is Comparable[] a good way to store all sorts of variables?

Tags: java, comparable

```
    Comparable w[] = new Comparable[5];
    w[0] = 1;
    w[1] = "string";
    w[2] = 2.0;
```

Is it a good way? And actually why does it work (I tried it just randomly)? Maybe because Comparable extends Integers, Strings, Doubles etc.? So what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it a good way?

If you can't think of a good reason to do some thing, its probably not a good idea. ;)

> Maybe because Comparable extends Integers, Strings, Doubles etc.?

Numbers and Strings implement Comparable, but you have the right idea.

> So what?

There are many odd things you can do in Java, but most of them don't have a use. ;)

In this case, its not particularly useful because the objects are not Comparable with each other. e.g. Arrays.sort(w); won't work.

Answer (score 2):

That works but it does not make much sense. `Integer`, `String` and `Double` do implement the `Comparable` interface, but in a generic way (i.e. `Integer` implements `Comparable<Integer>`, `String` implements `Comparable<String>` etc.).

So you won't be able to compare a `String` with a `Double` if that's what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a good idea. Use `Object[]` if you have to store such a 'heterogeneous' collection.
Specifying `Comparable` as a common interface also gives the false suggestion that you can sort the array, which is false since the different comparators can't cooperate.

Answer (score 1):

```
Comparable w[] = new Comparable[5];
```

This constructs an array of items that implement the comparable interface.
All the wrappers for standard types implement this interface so everything can be stored there.
The downside to this is that the compare methods are made to compare between objects of the same class. Putting items of different classes in this container defeats that purpose.

Because of that it is probably a bad idea to use the Comparable interface as the base type for your container. As it doesn't make sense.

A better option is to use Object[], which is the supertype of all Java objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use the interface of class defining the common useful property of the objects you want to store in your array or collection.

If you use the `compareTo` method, directly or not, for example by sorting your array, take Comparable. If not take Object as this would be less confusing for the reader. If not, be aware that choosing Comparable instead of Object this wouldn't limit the objects of your array in a useful way as there are many class implementing it (and it's growing).

But note that you rarely have to store in an array strings, doubles and integers. The fact that you have to is a signal you should check your design.

Answer (score 0):

**-** All `Wrapper Objects` implements `Comparable`, and thats how it works.

**-** Moreover Comparable is good when you need to **sort only according to one parameters**, but it would be good to use `Comparator` when you want to **sort in more than one way....**